# Prevent trigger Gitlab-ci job after git tagging

Tags: gitlab

I tried to create templates for other projects to create docker images.
My stages are create tag id, lint our code, and git tag push. ( We push our tag via GitLab API with **project access token**) I can create a Docker image with our template, but our pipeline tried to run again after our GitLab API tag request and got an error. ( `Project not found or access denied`) I tried several things to prevent rebuild. ( I used `git push -o ci.skip`  with the personal access token. It seems OK, but we don't want to use a personal access token in our pipelines) Could anyone help with that?

You can see my gitlab-ci template:

```
---
variables:
  http_proxy: ""
  https_proxy: ""
  no_proxy: ""


stages:
  - tag
  - lint
  - build
  - tagRelease

lint:
  stage: lint
  image: 
  script:
    - hadolint Dockerfile
    - |
      if  ls ./*.sh 1> /dev/null 2>&1  ; then
          echo "-------SH SCRIPT FOUND------------"
          shellcheck ./*.sh
      fi 
      if ls ./*.bash 1> /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
          echo "-------BASH SCRIPT FOUND------------"
          shellcheck ./*.bash
      fi
  tags:
    - DOCKER
    - AWS

createTag:
  stage: tag
  image:
    name: 
  script:
    - |
      LAST_BUILD_ID=$(git tag -l  | sort -V | tail -n 1  | cut -c 6,7,8 )
      echo "LAST_BUILD_ID=${LAST_BUILD_ID}"
      if [ -n "${LAST_BUILD_ID}" ] ; then
          BUILD_INDEX=$(( LAST_BUILD_ID + 1 ))
      else
          BUILD_INDEX=v1.0.0
      fi
      echo "BUILD_INDEX=${BUILD_INDEX}"
      export TAG="v1.0.${BUILD_INDEX}"
      echo "TAG=${TAG}"
      echo "TAG=${TAG}" > id.env
  only:
     refs:
       - master
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: id.env
  tags:
    - DOCKER
    - AWS
  
buildImageDevWithNoPush:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: 
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "-----------DOCKER BUILD STARTED. IMAGE WILL NOT BE PUSHED-------------" 
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --no-push --build-arg http_proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy=$https_proxy --build-arg no_proxy=$no_proxy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/.+$/'
  tags:
    - DOCKER
    - AWS
  
buildImageDevWithPush:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: 
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "-----------DOCKER BUILD STARTED. IMAGE WILL NOT BE PUSHED-------------" 
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:feature-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} --build-arg http_proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy=$https_proxy --build-arg no_proxy=$no_proxy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/.+$/'
      when: manual
  tags:
    - DOCKER
    - AWS
  

ProdBuildImage:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: 
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo ${TAG}
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "---------DOCKER BUILD STARTED------------"
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$TAG --build-arg http_proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy=$https_proxy --build-arg no_proxy=$no_proxy
  only:
     refs:
       - master
  dependencies:
    - createTag
  tags:
    - DOCKER
    - AWS

  - AWS

.tagRelease:
  stage: tagRelease
  script:
    - curl -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -X POST -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$CSC_API_TOKEN" --fail "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/tags?tag_name=$TAG&ref=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
```

Template Included by other project:

```
---
include:

  - project: ''
    ref: 'feature/pipeline_template'
    file: 'docker-build-template.yml'


tagRelease:
  extends: .tagRelease
  tags:
    - AWS
    - DOCKER
  except:
    - tags
```

Comment: this option can help tests_except_tags:

Comment: I already added except for all stages.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error report from Gitlab CI/CD pipeline?